# Edit partition of disk part of a ZFS Raid

Tags: arch-linux, mount, disk, zfs, gparted

I've got a strange problem.
Since a previous failure from one of my hard drive, I had to replace one of my 4 hdd running in RAIDZ.

But since I changed this disk, the last partition of my disk appeared on my desktop as a mountable device! But in gparted, is does not have a label set.

[image: Gparted drive /dev/sdf]

How could I remove the "CDROM" "drive" displaying on my desktop and file browser?

[image: Error while trying to mount]